# How to stream data from MPU6050+NodeMCU to Raspberry Pi?

Tags: nodemcu, mpu6050

I'm working on a small project, trying to wirelessly stream Accelerometer and Gyro data from 5 MPU6050 to my Raspberry pi at 100Hz via wifi. I've managed to configure the NodeMCUs to sample the data from my accelerometers, but now I'm a little confused with how to get that data over to Pi.

Ideally, I want to have something similar to a "Serial Monitor" seen in the Arduino environment but instead on my Pi terminal window. As far as I understand, I need to set-up a "SERVER" on my pi and then connect NodeMCUs to it as "CLIENTs" (I've found this library: https://github.com/ekstrand/ESP8266wifi.

Does this make sense? If so, can someone point me in a "getting started" guide on how to set-up a server like that on Pi 3B?

Answer (score 0):

Try this create a python script that will hit the web service where web service is the ip address of your nodemcu and from nodemcu send a JSON response parse the JSON response in your python script and display it.